# Доступ к функции другого срипта Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Скрипт 1:

```
public class spawnItems : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform[] SpawnPoints;
public float SpawnTime=4.0f;
public GameObject StealthMush;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    InvokeRepeating ("SpawnMush",SpawnTime,SpawnTime);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
public void SpawnMush()
{
    int spawnIndex = Random.Range (0,SpawnPoints.Length);
    Instantiate (StealthMush,SpawnPoints[spawnIndex].position, SpawnPoints[spawnIndex].rotation);
}
}
```

Скрипт 2:

```
public class hand : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform player;
public Transform mushrums;
public Transform mushrumsInv;
private Animator anim;
GameObject closest;
public GameObject invisibility_btn;
void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}
GameObject FindClosestEnemy() {
    GameObject[] gos;
    gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("mushrums");
    //GameObject closest;
    float distance = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    foreach (GameObject go in gos) {
        Vector3 diff = go.transform.position - position;
        float curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;
        if (curDistance < distance) {
            closest = go;
            distance = curDistance;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
public void HandUp () {

    float dist = Vector3.Distance(player.position, mushrums.position);
    float distInv = Vector3.Distance(player.position, mushrumsInv.position);
    Debug.Log(dist);
    Debug.Log(distInv);
    if (dist <= 59)
    {
        anim.Play("pick_up");
        Destroy(FindClosestEnemy());
    };
    if (distInv <= 21)
    {
        anim.Play("pick_up");
        CancelInvoke("SpawnMush");
        Destroy(FindClosestEnemy());
        invisibility_btn.SetActive(true);
    };

}

}
```

В 1 скрипте есть `InvokeRepeating ("SpawnMush",SpawnTime,SpawnTime);`
А остановить его нужно во 2 `CancelInvoke("SpawnMush");`
Как это сделать?

Comment: Сделайте в первом скрипте метод `Stop() { CancelInvoke("SpawnMush"); } ` ......а потом из второго в любой момент любым удобным способом вызовите этот самый метод `Stop()` первого скрипта

Comment: Кстати можете и дефолтным способом это сделать `GameObject.Find("Path/To/Object/On/Scene").GetComponent<spawnItems>().CancelInvoke("SpawnMush");`  Но способ со `Stop` более правильный, наверное, так как в том методе помимо `cancelInvoke` можно будет сделать любые другие еще операции какие захотите: установить или сбросить какие-либо флаги, сбросить что-то, очистить значения какие-нибудь и прочее